# Two tables vertically aligned, how to synchronise the widths/spacing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So that I can have a scrollable table with the heading row fixed at the top I have seperated the headers into their own table in a seperate div. The div below has the table data. The contents of the table varies and so I wish to be able to synchronise the top table with the spacings and widths of the rows below so that the header lines up exactly. How can I do this?

```
[header 1|header 2|header3]
[cell1       | cell2    |        cell3]
```

so that:

```
[header 1    | header 2|     header 3]
[cell1       | cell2   |        cell3]
```

Comment: please add the code snippets .

Comment: Can you post your code here and make a fiddle?

Comment: Why you use 2 tables? You can use <tbody> tag in one table and css it to be scrollable.

Comment: Here is working example: http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Comment: @bksi, it's not. Fixed widths(200px) in this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/gZTsr/6/

HTML:

```
    <div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="scrollTable">
<thead class="fixedHeader">
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="scrollContent">
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1 da widim dali she se sinkne kato mu nabiem kancheto s 200000 simvola otgore</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>And Repeat 1</td>
        <td>And Repeat 2</td>
        <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="normalRow">
        <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternateRow">
        <td>End of Cell Content 1</td>
        <td>End of Cell Content 2</td>
        <td>End of Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    font: normal normal 12px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0
}

div.tableContainer {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #963;
    height: 285px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 756px
}

/* Reset overflow value to hidden for all non-IE browsers. */
html>body div.tableContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 756px
}

/* define width of table. IE browsers only                 */
div.tableContainer table {
    float: left;
    width: 740px
}

/* define width of table. Add 16px to width for scrollbar.           */
/* All other non-IE browsers.                                        */
html>body div.tableContainer table {
    width: 756px
}

/* set table header to a fixed position. WinIE 6.x only                                       */
/* In WinIE 6.x, any element with a position property set to relative and is a child of       */
/* an element that has an overflow property set, the relative value translates into fixed.    */
/* Ex: parent element DIV with a class of tableContainer has an overflow property set to auto */
thead.fixedHeader tr {
    position: relative
}

/* set THEAD element to have block level attributes. All other non-IE browsers            */
/* this enables overflow to work on TBODY element. All other non-IE, non-Mozilla browsers */
html>body thead.fixedHeader tr {
    display: block
}

/* make the TH elements pretty */
thead.fixedHeader th {
    background: #C96;
    border-left: 1px solid #EB8;
    border-right: 1px solid #B74;
    border-top: 1px solid #EB8;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 4px 3px;
    text-align: left
}

/* make the A elements pretty. makes for nice clickable headers                */
thead.fixedHeader a, thead.fixedHeader a:link, thead.fixedHeader a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%
}

/* make the A elements pretty. makes for nice clickable headers                */
/* WARNING: swapping the background on hover may cause problems in WinIE 6.x   */
thead.fixedHeader a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 100%
}

/* define the table content to be scrollable                                              */
/* set TBODY element to have block level attributes. All other non-IE browsers            */
/* this enables overflow to work on TBODY element. All other non-IE, non-Mozilla browsers */
/* induced side effect is that child TDs no longer accept width: auto                     */
html>body tbody.scrollContent {
    display: block;
    height: 262px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%
}

/* make TD elements pretty. Provide alternating classes for striping the table */
/* http://www.alistapart.com/articles/zebratables/                             */
tbody.scrollContent td, tbody.scrollContent tr.normalRow td {
    background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
}

tbody.scrollContent tr.alternateRow td {
    background: #EEE;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
}

/* define width of TH elements: 1st, 2nd, and 3rd respectively.          */
/* Add 16px to last TH for scrollbar padding. All other non-IE browsers. */
/* http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors        */
html>body thead.fixedHeader th {
    width: 200px
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th + th {
    width: 240px
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th + th + th {
    width: 316px
}

/* define width of TD elements: 1st, 2nd, and 3rd respectively.          */
/* All other non-IE browsers.                                            */
/* http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors        */
html>body tbody.scrollContent td {
    width: 200px
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent td + td {
    width: 240px
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent td + td + td {
    width: 300px
}
-->
```

This is just ilustration. You can css all the cells if you want.

Comment: But the columns are not aligned? one cell per each header column.

Comment: hi, thanks for this, but as I say, I have two tables, one with header cells, and the other with the main data cells. Each are in seperate divs, can you span a single table over two divs?

Comment: as i said you don't need 2 tables for that. It is very hard to sync 2 tables cells widths.

Comment: but then the headers will scroll with the data which I want them to be fixed at the top so I put them in separate div.

Comment: yeah.. if you put a long string in any of the data fields, the headers don't align with the new cell width

Comment: If you think that this is correct answer, mark it as correct :)

Comment: It isn't working though, if you put any extra characters in the tds, the ths don't synchronise... sorry mate

Comment: :( I hate this hell: `td+td+td{width: xpx;}`

Answer (score 0):

since an understandable table should be made of one piece , to span them is not a good idea.
You could set width from  tag or id/class, but thead & tbody needs to remain in the flow to extend together.

One trick is to clone thead into a tfoot. (no problem to me to see at bottm of table a reminder of headers , you read a table in 2-D :) .

So tfoot cloned can be set on position:absolute.

To avoid issues with position:relative, wrap your table in a container. it will be in charge to keep tfoot on top and scroll.

demo : http://dabblet.com/gist/5648624 
(if you want to use IE, you need to copy/paste CSS/HTML codes into a codepen or a jsfiddle dabblet doesnt't like iE :( )
a table can be structured like this:

```
table
   caption
   thead
   tfoot
   tbody
```

No matter where are tfoot, tbody or thead, they'll take position at screen