# Scroll Table with Html/CSS

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table

I have a table like this one:

[image]

What I want to do is to make it scrollabe after certing height or certain number of rows, keeping the header Bike - Car - Truck visible. I have made enough Google searches, seen other Stack Overflow posts like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834198/table-scroll-with-html-and-css). I have tried the jsfiddle.net solution in the accepted answer of that post as well. But it makes my table looks like this:

[image]

Here is the link to my [html](http://pastebin.com/PhNY8H03) code. It might seem untidy, I have just pasted table data to see if the scrolling works. This one is the [tablestyle.css](http://pastebin.com/t7G5d9iK). I think the public.css file has nothing to do with this distortion. If it is important then I shall upload that as well. Any clues/helps are appreciated!

Comment: i think if you put your table inside a div and give that div a css class with fixed height and overflow:auto; will fix your issue

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878941/two-tables-vertically-aligned-how-to-synchronise-the-widths-spacing

Comment: @Sora it worked but the scroll bar moved to far right where the browser scroll bar would be sitting :(

Comment: **ID's** are meant to be unique. use **class** instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added the following css to fix it:

In HTML I wrapped the first `tr` with `thead` (*not necessary, but recommended*)

**CSS**:

```
table.list {
    width:100%;
}
table.list thead {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
table.list thead th {
    text-align: center;
}
table.list tbody {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
table.list tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
table.list th, td {
    width: 25%;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/6HKsB/1/)

You may want to make this fix cross-browser. Then please go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16984323/1577396).

Comment: Your solution works fine. I am just curious, since I will be inserting this table inside another table layout, so far I know, if we want to distinguish conflicting css elements, we use id/class. You have used just table {widht:100%;}, so will it conflict when I link other css files containing table ?

Comment: @Pro.metal I don't think so. but it would be better if you give some class to the table in my above solution.

Comment: @Pro.metal check my updated post. I am assuming the class would be `.list` here. (_I have not updated the fiddle though_) I hope you can understand it better now. :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

I have changed some of your css

```
tbody#scrolling { height: 120px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y:scroll; display: block;}
td#vehicles, th#vehicles {  border: 0 none; height: 30px; min-width:153px; }
thead{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

also added `thead` in the `table`

here is [jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/nz5Db/)

Also you have used one ID multiple time in you table, which is not a valid code. change it to class.

Comment: it works, but there's still a problem. if there are lesser number of rows, then the scroll bar is still there. Mr_Green solution doesn't have that problem. +1 for the solution :)