# Trying to "lock" the tableheader rows & struggling

Tags: html, css

Just when I think I'm starting to get a grip on CSS, I try something new and realize how much I still have to learn :(

I've created a table and I'm trying to lock down the header rows so they don't scroll off the page.  The snippet below is as close as I've got to making it work, but as you can see it's a mess.  If you remove the class from the table, you can see what it should look like.  I've played with the display/position settings, but it seems like when I get one thing corrected, it breaks another.  Guess that's what happens when you don't really understand what you're doing.

Could somebody take a look and let me know where I'm messing this up at, please??

```css
.fixed_headers {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.fixed_headers thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: static;
}
.fixed_headers tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 125px;
}
```

```html
<table class="fixed_headers">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color:LightGoldenrodYellow;">
      <th colspan="2"></th>
      <th colspan="10">YTD (Completed Months Only)
        <br/>(54 Attendance Days) 8/10/2015 - 10/30/2015</th>
      <th colspan="10">Student Month 1 (18 Attendance Days)
        <br/>8/10/2015 - 9/4/2015</th>
      <th colspan="10">Student Month 2 (18 Attendance Days)
        <br/>9/7/2015 - 10/2/2015</th>
      <th colspan="10">Student Month 3 (18 Attendance Days)
        <br/>10/5/2015 - 10/30/2015</th>
      <th colspan="10">Student Month 4 <span style='color:red'>(In Progress)</span> (4 Attendance Days)
        <br/>11/2/2015 - 12/2/2015</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:LightGoldenrodYellow;">
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      <th colspan="2">Attendance Rate</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Enrollment Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Missed Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Lost Revenue</th>
      <th colspan="2">Instructional Hours Lost</th>
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      <th colspan="2">Attendance Rate</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Enrollment Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Missed Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Lost Revenue</th>
      <th colspan="2">Instructional Hours Lost</th>
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      <th colspan="2">Attendance Rate</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Enrollment Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Missed Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Lost Revenue</th>
      <th colspan="2">Instructional Hours Lost</th>
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      <th colspan="2">Attendance Rate</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Enrollment Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Missed Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Lost Revenue</th>
      <th colspan="2">Instructional Hours Lost</th>
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      <th colspan="2">Attendance Rate</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Enrollment Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Missed Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Lost Revenue</th>
      <th colspan="2">Instructional Hours Lost</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:LightGoldenrodYellow;">
      <th colspan="2"></th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr align="center">
      <td align="center">Laukhuf Elementary</td>
      <td>K</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td align="center">Kerrick Elementary</td>
      <td>K</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Someone just asked this question a little while ago.  I suggest putting the headers in a separate DIV outside of the scrollable area.

Comment: This is a little more involved then people understand. A quick google search lead me [to this JS.Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/) which should lead you in the right path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878941/two-tables-vertically-aligned-how-to-synchronise-the-widths-spacing/16879157#16879157
I dont even remember when was this question asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add position relative to your table, then set thead position absolute.

```css
.fixed_headers {
  table-layout: fixed;
  position:relative;
}

th div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
.fixed_headers thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: static;
}
.fixed_headers tbody {
  margin-top:100px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 125px;
}
&th {min-width:100px}
```

```html
<table class="fixed_headers">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color:LightGoldenrodYellow;">
      <th colspan="2"></th>
      <th colspan="10"><div>YTD (Completed Months Only)
        <br/>(54 Attendance Days) 8/10/2015 - 10/30/2015</div></th>
      <th colspan="10"><div>Student Month 1 (18 Attendance Days)
        <br/>8/10/2015 - 9/4/2015</div></th>
      <th colspan="10"><div>Student Month 2 (18 Attendance Days)
        <br/>9/7/2015 - 10/2/2015d</div></th>
      <th colspan="10"><div>Student Month 3 (18 Attendance Days)
        <br/>10/5/2015 - 10/30/2015</div></th>
      <th colspan="10"><div>Student Month 4 <span style='color:red'>(In Progress)</span> (4 Attendance Days)
        <br/>11/2/2015 - 12/2/2015</div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:LightGoldenrodYellow;">
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      <th colspan="2">Attendance Rate</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Enrollment Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Missed Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Lost Revenue</th>
      <th colspan="2">Instructional Hours Lost</th>
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      <th colspan="2">Attendance Rate</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Enrollment Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Missed Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Lost Revenue</th>
      <th colspan="2">Instructional Hours Lost</th>
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      <th colspan="2">Attendance Rate</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Enrollment Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Missed Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Lost Revenue</th>
      <th colspan="2">Instructional Hours Lost</th>
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      <th colspan="2">Attendance Rate</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Enrollment Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Missed Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Lost Revenue</th>
      <th colspan="2">Instructional Hours Lost</th>
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      <th colspan="2">Attendance Rate</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Enrollment Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total Missed Days</th>
      <th colspan="2">Lost Revenue</th>
      <th colspan="2">Instructional Hours Lost</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:LightGoldenrodYellow;">
      <th colspan="2"></th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
      <th>CY</th>
      <th>PY</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr align="center">
      <td align="center">Laukhuf Elementary</td>
      <td>K</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td align="center">Kerrick Elementary</td>
      <td>K</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>

      <td>95.75%</td>
      <td>97.33%</td>
      <td>4,002</td>
      <td>4,211</td>
      <td>170</td>
      <td>112.5</td>
      <td>$1,932.90</td>
      <td>$1,279.13</td>
      <td>1,020</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for the answer...I actually saw the jsfiddle that @crazymatt shared before asking this...but it seems to be missing a class, headers...and when i was playing around with it I couldn't get it to work.  But I just tried it again and it's working fine, so I guess I accidentally deleted something when playing with it yesterday :)