# I need a fixed table header with a scrollable body. I have tried everything but it won't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link href="../../../CSS/StatePage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="sorttable.js"></script>

<header>
<h1>
<a href="../../OpenPage.html"> <img src="../../logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="30" height="30"/></a>Title</h1>
<h6>small header</h6>   
</header>

<br> <br>
<br> <br>
<br>
<div>
<table id="states"
       align="center"
       class="sortable"
>

<thead>
    <tr>    
        <th><h4>Table title 1</h4></th>
        <th><h4>Table title 2</h4></th>
        <th><h4>Table title 3</h4></th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>

</table>
</div>



<footer>
<h2> Footer Name </h2>
</footer>

</html>
```

/////// Here is my CSS

```
h1, h2, h6 { 
font-family: Helvetica;
text-align: center;
}

header {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0px;
border-bottom: solid;
height: 99px;
}

tr, td {
padding: 5px;
}

table {
margin-top: 5px;
}

/* Sortable tables */
table.sortable thead {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #E5855F;
    cursor: default;
}


tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #FFC792;
}

thead {
font-family: Helvetica;
text-align: left;
}

tbody {
overflow: auto;
}

a:link {
color: black; 
}

footer {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: auto;
bottom: 0px;
border-top: solid;
}
```

Comment: I have been stuck on this for a about a week now. Everytime I try to use a javascript that is out there, it seems to just not work with my code. All i really need is a fixed table header but cant seem to figure it out. I have been on all of the top 50 google searches, but no results. I think something basic must be wrong with my code

Comment: Have you tried best plugin there, the [DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878941/two-tables-vertically-aligned-how-to-synchronise-the-widths-spacing/16879157#16879157

Comment: `but it won't seem to work` is not a real question.  Usually questions ask something.  And they have a question mark.  See? Like this?

Comment: My question i guess is how to make the table have a fixed header and the body scrollable. I thought that was clear.

Comment: No its not. If you have a question then ask it outright.  Don't imply your question.

Comment: Here's a question for you. Please stop.

Answer (score -1):

If you set the display properties of thead and tbody to "inline-block" you get scrolling. May not be exactly what you need but you'll have to tweek it.

Also you have to wrap the table in a container div so the elements don't "fall out"

```
thead {

  width: 290px;
  display: inline-block;
}

tbody {

  width: 290px;
display: inline-block;
height: 70px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

table {
margin-top: 5px;

}

tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


#table-cont {


  width: 290px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m12x44mo/1/